# Are pickpocket encounters repeatable?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I'm currently on bandit challenge 7 (50$ cash and valuables from robbing townsfolk and travellers) and would like to avoid having to rob 50 people, given the usual haul. I know that catching a pickpocket would give me a convient way to finish the challenge without requiring grinding it (especially grindy due to the honor loss).

However, I already ran into two of them beforehand and now can't seem to trigger another occurance of this particular kind of encounter - are these one-off encounters which cannot be repeated?

Are there maybe locations I missed, where it could also happen? (I've only had it happen in St. Denis)

Answer (score 2):

Some important things to [note](https://www.rdr2.org/forums/topic/1917-random-encounters-question-advice-pls/)

> There's a difference between stranger missions, stranger dialogues, stranger ongoing events, random encounters, and quests.
>
> For example, a stranger mission series is indicated by a question mark or letters in a white zone on the map.  These are missable and time-sensitive.  Some of these optional missions arise from camp members.  Some are unlocked at only set chapters, some have prerequisites, some only open at set honor ranks.
>
> A random encounter is a white dot echo on the map, and some/many of these respawn or reoccur.
>
> stranger dialogues are when you have non-mission interactions with weirdoes across the map.  They are usually multiple staged and change post epilogue.  In that sense they are time-sensitive.
>
> ongoing events, like the home building, follow set time/place patterns and you can either join in at that time, or at a later stage (it will be different), or miss them.  It's hard to do all theses without knowing them in advance.
>
> some camp member item requests are only available at certain chapters after certain interactions - like playing poker with person X during chapter 3 - they are easily missable.
>
> easter eggs vary between places of special interest, unique items, unique documents, and time-sensitive events (being a certain place and time).

These are random events that occur all over RDR2 in a way to give a feeling of more life. My understanding is if you complete a chance encounter and it's successful then the encounter will not occur again.

If you fail a random encounter then the encounter will "respawn" and have a chance to be completed again. There doesn't seem to be a defined time for these to happen, most likely the best thing to do is go to another part of the map and pass a few in-game days, once you've passed them you can go back and look to trigger the chance encounter.

I'm unsure what exactly your situation falls under but this should hopefully help.